# Which context uses a function that was passed as an argument?

Tags: javascript

to I ran into a problem with the context of a function that is passed as an argument.

The following Code shows the initial situation.

```
...

        this._handleListener(cb.fromObj.addEventListener);
},

_handleListener: function(func) {
        func('vr-resize', this.ConnectionBehavior.resize);
        func('vr-delete', this.ConnectionBehavior.delete);
},

...
```

The code snippet didn't work as expected. After changing the second line and bind the context from **cb.fromObj** to the function it worked.

Changed line looks like this:

```
this._handleListener(cb.fromObj.addEventListener.bind(cb.fromObj));
```

Now are my question: Why do I need bind? Which context does the function use without bind?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should fix your indenting. Many people will ignore your question if the code is too illegible.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Oh come on, this is pretty good in the grand scheme of things…